# Grails selectively caching queries

Tags: hibernate, grails, caching, second-level-cache, query-cache

I have second level cache and query cache enabled in my grails application and have set grails.hibernate.cache.queries=false to be able to selectively cache queries. Inspite of this I see that queries are cached in StandardQueryCache. Settings in my application are as follows:

```
grails.hibernate.cache.queries=false in Config.groovy
cache.use_query_cache = true in Datasource.groovy
cache.region.factory_class = 'grails.plugin.cache.ehcache.hibernate.BeanEhcacheRegionFactory'
```

I tried to check queryCache entries as follows :

```
sessionFactory.queryCache.region.ehcache.keys
```

as was mentioned in [How to get entries from the second level query cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841885/how-to-get-entries-from-the-second-level-query-cache)

If I specify cache:false explicitly in the dynamic or criteria query it is not getting caches. I would like to selectively cache query results. Am I missing some thing here.